# What does the double vertical bar mean here?

Tags: impedance, math-notation

I'm reading on air "gap impedance" and came across this equation from these notes on the topic. http://web.mit.edu/6.685/www/chapter8.pdf (see page 7).
The article defines this equation as: The “gap impedance”, or the impedance looking to the right from the right-most terminal of X1 is:

$$Z_g=jX_m||(jX_2+\frac{R_2}{s})$$

What do the double vertical bars mean in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is standard notation in electrical engineering, used for parallel impedances. It can be defined as

$$x\ ||\ y \triangleq\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}}$$

In other words, if you have an X Ω resistor in parallel with a Y Ω resistor, the equivalent resistance of the two will be X || Y Ω. When speaking, X || Y would be pronounced as "X parallel Y" or "X in parallel with Y".

---

However, it can also just mean that two things are in parallel, so the mathematical definition above may not work if, for instance, you're talking about a resistor in parallel with an inductor, which might be written as 10 μH || 1 kΩ. Obviously, using the definition above in this case breaks down, as the units don't add up properly—you'd need to convert them to impedances first. For instance, I've seen the impedance of [a standard CISPR 16-1-2 LISN](https://schwarzbeck.de/en/lisn-line-impedance-stabilisation-networks/v-lisn-en/v-lisn-cispr-16-1-2.html) described as "50 Ω || (50 μH + 5 Ω)".

Likewise, even when the mathematical definition may work, it's probably not what is meant when someone writes "1 μF || 100 nF", as capacitance is an admittance parameter, not an impedance parameter. It still means the two capacitors are in parallel, but since parallel capacitances add, the proper definition to use here would be

$$x\ ||\ y \triangleq x + y\ \scriptsize{\mathrm{(for\ capacitances\ and\ admittances)}}.$$

There isn't really any equivalent notation for describing admittances in series, which use the same harmonic sum formula shown above for impedances in parallel.